# PHP / MySQL - Cross referencing mysql_fetch_array data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am populating a table using PHP / MySQL.
It displays the classification id instead of the classification name so I need to cross reference the classifications table to obtain the name.
Now I can do this within the loop for each row in the table by adding a MySQL query such as `"SELECT classification_name from classifications WHERE classification_id = $row['classification']";`

I feel this would cause unnecessary strain on SQL as for a large number of rows I'll be initialising a lot of SQL queries.

I can bring the classifications table into a PHP array and cross reference it but is there an easier way to cross reference two sets of SQL data (with one outside of the loop).

I think I am being daft as I'm sure there is an easier method I have used in the past.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Thanks eggyyal - looks like a good link. I'm trying to left join 4 tables now so that might be the extra help I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done in a query using a `JOIN`; getting information this way using PHP would be incredibly inefficient for your system.

Comment: Ah joins... yes, exactly :) I shall research further now you've hit on the search terms I need. Thank you.

Comment: SELECT * FROM sch_part_general, sch_classifications WHERE sch_part_general.classification = sch_classifications.classification_id

This worked great. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesPitt, you should also look at using modern JOIN syntax... that style of join is considered deprecated.

Comment: Quite right. In the end I needed classification, category, and subcategory to display the name, rather than id. Those were stored in separate tables so the query became...
SELECT sch_part_general.*, sch_classifications.classification_name, sch_category.category_name, sch_sub_category.sub_category_name FROM sch_part_general LEFT JOIN sch_classifications ON sch_part_general.classification = classifications.classification_id LEFT JOIN sch_category ON sch_part_general.category = sch_category.category_id LEFT JOIN sch_sub_category ON sch_part_general.sub_category = sch_sub_category.sub_category_id